# Django Rest Framework page doesn't show POST results in certain circumstances

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm working on an application that uses the Django Rest Framework.  For testing purposes, we occasionally use the default Django Rest Framework page for debugging or testing purposes.

Another developer recently discovered, that with one of our endpoints (that only has a POST method on it) immediately redirects without showing the last posted content of the POST call.  The redirect results in an HTTP 405 (method not allowed).  This behaviour is unlike most of our other endpoints - even those that only have a POST option.  when they are posted to, they show the content of the POST call, as well as the text box that allows another POST.

In digging into this, I discovered that this particular endpoint was returning a response in the form of an HttpResponse object, rather than a Response object.  It was also specifying the `application/json` content-type for the HttpResponse object.

In playing around with this, I discovered that if I switch it to use a Response object it doesn't cause the Django Rest Framework page to redirect, and does show the response on the page.  However, if I specify the content_type on the Response object, the Django Rest Framework page starts redirecting again, without showing the last posted content.

In any of these situations, it is still possible to see the response by resorting to using the Chrome Developer tools and enabling "Preserve log", so that the network call history isn't cleared with the redirect, however this is less than ideal.

In changing it to use the Response instead of HttpResponse objects, it also broke one of our unit tests, as the unit test wasn't specifying the content-type header of `application/json`, but was expecting a JSON response.  There may be other places that are also calling it without specifying the content-type header, so ideally I would like to be able to specify a content-type on the response, but still have the Django Rest Framework page show the last POSTed content.

My questions are thus:

- What causes the default Django Rest Framework page to display the last posted content (as opposed to redirecting)?
- Why does specifying a content-type on the Response cause the Django Rest Framework page to not display the last posted content?

Comment: Django REST framework doesn't redirect. Your code seems to do something wrong and possible your exception handler or some middleware redirects upon error, maybe one page redirects to some login

Comment: It's definitely Django Rest Framework doing something.  After the POST is made, the page refreshes, and any previously displayed content is gone.  So it might not be redirecting, but it's definitely not displaying the contents of the post that caused the refresh.

Comment: Unfortunately it lacks relevant informations to figure.

Comment: Thankfully it's a pretty low priority issue.  Perhaps I'll get another chance to look at it later on.